# Matching generic types in Scala macros

Tags: scala, generics, macros, types

I have a Scala (2.10) def macro with argument *x*. It's body looks like this:

```
if (x.actualType =:= typeOf[generic.Type[String]]) {
  // branch 1: do something with x
}
else {
  // branch 2: do something else
}
```

The implementation of the **generic.Type** class itself is not accessible and its implementation cannot be modified. Now, I'd like this macro to call branch 1 not just for **generic.Type[String]** s, but for **generic.Type[T]** , where *T* is any type.

Is there a canonical way to achieve that? Or is the only option doing it manually using the AST?

Comment: what is the macro signature?

Comment: It's def impl(c : Context)(x : c.Expr[Any]) : c.Expr[Any]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `x.actualType.typeSymbol == typeOf[generic.Type[_]].typeSymbol`

Comment: Types represent Scala types, such as `Foo[Bar]` or even something really complex like `Foo forSome { type Bar <: Baz }`. Symbols represent Scala definitions (every definition has one and only one symbol associated with it). Therefore, the right way of checking whether something (e.g. a component of a type) refers to some definition is to compare symbols.